# Subquerying To Obtain Specific Values From Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-server-2016, querying

I need help with querying and will do my best to explain my issue. I have the following table below of 11 rows which is created from importing values from SharePoint list.

```
  ID   SHPT_ID  STATUS_DESC  REC_UPDT_DTTM  REC_CRTE_DTTM   EXPIR_DT
   1    270      Active      1-18-2019     1-19-2019     1-24-2019   
   2    270      In Progress 1-23-2019     1-24-2019     2-3-2019
   3    270      Completed   2-2-2019      2-3-2019      2-19-2019
   4    270      Completed   2-18-2019     2-19-2019    2-28-2019 
   5    270      In Progress 2-27-2019     2-28-2019    3-2-2019
   6    270      Completed   3-1-2019      3-2-2019     3-6-2019
   7    270      Completed   3-5-2019      3-6-2019     12-31-9999
   8    295      Active      12-20-2018    12-21-2018   12-26-2018
   9    295      Completed   12-25-2018    12-26-2018   12-31-9999
   10   345      Active      6-7-2017      6-8-2017     6-14-2017
   11   345      Completed   6-13-2017     6-14-2017    6-22-2017
   12   345      Completed   6-21-2017     6-22-2017    12-31-9999
```

The last record associated to a particular SharePoint ID brings in the EXPIR_DT (Expire Date) of '12/31/9999'. Everytime a value in the SharePoint ID record is updated, a new row is created.

From this table, I am trying to pull back 3 rows in particular (rows where ID = #6, 9, and 11.)

These are the records having the minimum REC_UPDT_DTTM when STATUS_DESC equals 'Completed' for the last time. For the rows where SharePoint ID = 270, there is an instance when the record was 'Completed' but was reversed to 'In Process' and then later was put back in to 'Completed.' For this record, it should not take the row where ID =3, it should take the row where ID = 6.

Is there anyone who can help me with this code as I am stuck with how to proceed to get the rows that I want? I know I have to use subquerying and functions but I am really stuck at the moment.

Please let me know if need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query works for the dataset above. However, if a SHPT_ID could have two Completed records on the same day, this will return two rows for that SHPT_ID:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM MyTable m
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Min(Rec_UPDT_DTTM) MinUpdt,
        Shpt_ID
    FROM MyTable m1
    WHERE Status_Desc = 'Completed'
       AND NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT *
           FROM MyTable m2
           WHERE m2.Shpt_ID = m1.Shpt_ID
               AND m2.REC_UPDT_DTTM > m1.REC_UPDT_DTTM
               AND m2.Status_Desc <> 'Completed'
            )
    ) filter
    ON filter.MinUpdt = m.REC_UPDT_DTTM
    AND filter.Shpt_ID = m.Shpt_ID
```

To handle the case with duplicates on the same day, the code would look like this:

```
SELECT MyTable.*
FROM MyTable
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Shpt_ID, 
        MIN(ID) as ID
    FROM MyTable m
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Min(Rec_UPDT_DTTM) MinUpdt,
            Shpt_ID
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE Status_Desc = 'Completed'
       AND NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT *
           FROM MyTable m2
           WHERE m2.Shpt_ID = m1.Shpt_ID
               AND m2.REC_UPDT_DTTM > m1.REC_UPDT_DTTM
               AND m2.Status_Desc <> 'Completed'
            )
        ) filter
        ON filter.MinUpdt = MyTable.REC_UPDT_DTTM
        AND filter.Shpt_ID = MyTable.Shpt_ID
    ) as IDs
    ON MyTable.ID = IDs.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MIN` and `GROUP BY`. Something like:

`SELECT [ID], [SHPT_ID], [STATUS_DESC], MIN(REC_UPDT_DTTM), [REC_CRTE_DTTM], [EXPIR_DT] FROM [myTable] WHERE [STATUS_DESC] = 'Completed' GROUP BY [SHPT_ID]`.

Comment: This won't return the full row, just a subset of the data. OP asked for the full row.

Comment: You can use this as a subquery, if a list of primary key ID's is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your problem, but since the date format is mm-dd-yyyy, 2-2-2019 (#3) is less than 3-1-2019 (#6).

Comment: Yes, that's why I said for that particular Sharepoint ID..it was originally Completed and then taken from that status. It was then put again in Completed after "In Process."